# Page gets reloaded on form submit.Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, preventdefault

I have implemented a controlled Form using react hooks.
I have also added the event.preventDefault() call to the form submit handler.
But for some reason, the form submit always causes a page refresh even then.
I am not sure why.

I have checked other threads in StackOverflow and checking the answers, what I did is correct.
I am just not able

Below is my code..
What am I doing wrong?

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import style from './style.css'
import {Link,useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {builderUpdateRequest,selectBuilders} from "../../data/builder"


const PageBuilderForm=()=>{
    let { id } = useParams();

    const allBuilders=useSelector(selectBuilders)
    const selectedBuilder=allBuilders?allBuilders.find(x=>x.id==id):null;
    const [formData,setFormData]=useState(selectedBuilder)
    const dispatch=useDispatch();

    const onSubmitHandler=(e)=>{ 
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(builderUpdateRequest(formData));
    }

    const handleChange=(e)=>{
        const newFormData={ ...formData};
        newFormData[e.currentTarget.name]=e.currentTarget.value;
        setFormData({
            ...newFormData,
        })
    }

    if(selectedBuilder){
        return(
        <div className={style.formContainer}>
            <form className={style.form} onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
                <div className={style.formLabel}>Developer Logo Image URL</div>
                <div className={style.formField}><input type="url" name="logo" value={formData.logo} onChange={handleChange} required/></div>


                <div className={style.formLabel}>Developer Name</div>
                <div className={style.formField}><input type="text" name="title" value={formData.title} onChange={handleChange} required/></div>


                <div className={style.formLabel}>Years of Experience</div>
                <div className={style.formField}><input type="number" name="totalExp" value={formData.totalExp} onChange={handleChange} required/></div>


                <div className={style.formLabel}>Projects Count</div>
                <div className={style.formField}><input type="number" name="totalProjects" value={formData.totalProjects} onChange={handleChange} required/></div>


                <div className={style.formLabel}>Description</div>
                <div className={style.formField}><input type="text" name="desc" value={formData.desc} onChange={handleChange} required maxlength={200}/></div>


                <div className={style.formLabel}>Project Name</div>
                <div className={style.formField}><input type="text" name="imgTitle" value={formData.imgTitle} onChange={handleChange} required maxlength={40}/></div>


                <div className={style.formLabel}>Project Location</div>
                <div className={style.formField}><input type="text" name="location" value={formData.location} onChange={handleChange} required maxlength={40}/></div>


                <div className={style.formLabel}>Project image URL</div>
                <div className={style.formField}><input type="url" name="imgURL" value={formData.imgURL} onChange={handleChange} required/></div>

                <div className={style.formField}>
                    <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
                </div>
            </form>
            <Link className={style.home}to="/">Go Home</Link>
        </div>
    )
    }
    else{
        return <Link className={style.home}to="/">Go Home</Link>
    }
    
}

export default PageBuilderForm;
```

Comment: could you create a reproducible issue?

Comment: can you share what does import {builderUpdateRequest,selectBuilders} from "../../data/builder"
 do ?

Comment: @PrateekThapa I didnt understand what you meant.Do you mean if the page reload issue is reproducible?Yes,it is.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal they are just redux action creators and selectors

Comment: Page refresh occurs if your App component is re rendered so check if your action is doing something to cause app component to re render

Comment: @MohammadFaisal the dispatch causes a side effect..an async api call.That should not have caused a page refresh

Comment: As a debugging step it's useful to strip out non-essential stuff from your code bit by bit until (hopefully) the problem disappears. If that happens you have identified the area of interest, and if that doesn't happen, you have created a minimal reproducible example. Bonus if the example is runnable from codepen of similar. For more details check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @squall3d thank you.I was debugging the issue and found that the page refresh happens after dispatching an action to trigger an api call.If I don't dispatch an action on form submit, the page doesn't reload /refresh.
The dispatched action triggers an api call to update backend with form data using the fetch api.

Comment: Even more confused as to why it's happening.

Comment: Did some more debugging in browser and founf the exact code where reload is happening:
```
connection.onmessage = function(e) {
  var message = JSON.parse(e.data);
  switch (message.type) {
    case 'hash':
      handleAvailableHash(message.data);
      break;
    case 'still-ok':
    case 'ok':
      handleSuccess();
      break;
    case 'content-changed':
      // Triggered when a file from `contentBase` changed.
      window.location.reload();
```
Its got something to do with the hot reload feature?This code resides in webpackhotdevclient.js which deals with hot reload.

Comment: it was an issue with hot reload of web pack dev server apparently.Once I disabled the hot reload, page stopped refreshing on form submit.
Pretty weird as to why dev server was reloading in the first place.Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging some more,I found out that the reload was happening due to the webpack hot reload feature.Once I disabled the hot reload in webpack dev server, my page stopped refreshing on form submit.
Pretty weird and surprising as to why this is happening in dev server.I am now curious as to why the dev server is performing a hot reload after an api call to update the data entered in forms.

I modified these settings in webpackDevServer.config.js

```js
watchContentBase: false,
    // Enable hot reloading server. It will provide WDS_SOCKET_PATH endpoint
    // for the WebpackDevServer client so it can learn when the files were
    // updated. The WebpackDevServer client is included as an entry point
    // in the webpack development configuration. Note that only changes
    // to CSS are currently hot reloaded. JS changes will refresh the browser.
   hot: false,
```

Comment: How did you fix this issue? where webpackDevServer.config.js is located? I am using react

Answer (score 0):

When I use onSubmit as prevent its working like as:

```
const Submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Information Is Received");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={Submit}>
        <div className="Dcontainer">
          <h1 className="heading">Hello, {inputValue.uName}</h1>
          <p>{inputValue.email}</p>
          <p>{inputValue.password}</p>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Your Name"
            name="uName"
            // value ={inputValue.uName}
            onChange={inputEvent}
          />
          <input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter Your Email"
            name="email"
            // value={inputValue.email}
            onChange={inputEvent}
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter Your Password"
            name="password"
            // value={inputValue.password}
            onChange={inputEvent}
          />
          <button className="primary__btn" type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```